# Sorting a list with two parameters using CompareTo

Tags: c#, list, sorting, compareto

I am presently sorting a C# list using the 'CompareTo' method in the object type contained in the list. I want to sort ascendingly all items by their WBS (Work Breakdown Structure) and I can manage this very well using the following code:

```
        public int CompareTo(DisplayItemsEntity other)
        {
            string[] instanceWbsArray = this.WBS.Split('.');
            string[] otherWbsArray = other.WBS.Split('.');

            int result = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < maxLenght; i++)
            {
                if (instanceWbsArray[i].Equals(otherWbsArray[i]))
                {
                    continue;
                }
                else
                {    
                    result = Int32.Parse(instanceWbsArray[i]).CompareTo(Int32.Parse(otherWbsArray[i]));
                    break;
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
```

Now, I would like to be able to sort considering more than one parameter, as in the project name alphabetically, before considering the second which would be the WBS. How can I do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't know the details of your class, so I'll provide an example using a list of strings and LINQ. `OrderBy` will order the strings alphabetically, `ThenBy` will order them by their lengths afterwards. You can adapt this sample to your needs easily enough.

```
var list = new List<string>
{
    "Foo",
    "Bar",
    "Foobar"
};
var sortedList = list.OrderBy(i => i).
    ThenBy(i => i.Length).
    ToList();
```

Comment: How can I use the 'OrderBy()' method?

Comment: @JFB Assuming that you are using .NET 3.5 or greater, you need to include in your file's `using` directives: `using System.Linq;`

Comment: oops! now I'm embarrassed. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

What we generally do in cases like yours is this:

```
public int CompareTo( SomeClass other )
{
    int result = this.SomeProperty.CompareTo( other.SomeProperty );
    if( result != 0 )
        return result;
    result = this.AnotherProperty.CompareTo( other.AnotherProperty );
    if( result != 0 )
        return result;
    [...]
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I like Eve's answer because of it's flexibility but I'm kinda surprised that no-one has mentioned creating a custom [`IComparer<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ehhxeaf.aspx) instance

`IComparer<T>` is a generic interface that defines a method for comparing two instances of the type `T`.  The advantage of using `IComparer<T>` is that you can create implementations for each sort order you commonly use and then use these as and when necessary.  This allows you to  create a default sort order in the types `CompareTo()` method and define alternative orders separately.

E.g.

```
public class MyComparer
 : IComparer<YourType>
{
  public int Compare(YourType x, YourType y)
  {
     //Add your comparison logic here
  }
}
```

`IComparer<T>` is particularly useful for composition where you can do things like have a comparer which compares some properties of a given type using another comparer that operates on the type of the property.

It's also very useful if you ever need to define a sorting on a type you don't control.  Another advantage it has is it doesn't require LINQ so can be used in older code (.Net 2.0 onwards)

Answer (score 0):

First compare the project name alphabetically and if they are not equal return value, if not perform comparison based on second value

```
    public int CompareTo(DisplayItemsEntity other)
    {
       if(other.ProjectName.CompareTo(this.ProjectName) != 0)
       {
           return other.ProjectName.CompareTo(this.ProjectName)
       }

       //else do the second comparison and return


       return result;
    }
```